# Excel Loading via c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Try to Load an excel file using this code below gives me this error

The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet Name'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Sheet Name' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.

i am sure the Sheet Name is correct.

Any suggestions?

```
if (strFile.Trim().EndsWith(".xlsx"))
{
   strConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";", strFile);
}
else if (strFile.Trim().EndsWith(".xls"))
{
    strConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";", strFile);
}


OleDbConnection SQLConn = new OleDbConnection(strConnectionString);
SQLConn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter SQLAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
string sql = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";
OleDbCommand selectCMD = new OleDbCommand(sql, SQLConn);
SQLAdapter.SelectCommand = selectCMD;

///error in this line
SQLAdapter.Fill(dtXLS);
SQLConn.Close();
```

Comment: This may be weird, but try putting a `$` at the end of the sheet name.

Comment: I might be missing it but sheetname is not being set in the code you posted. Is it set further up?

Comment: Also I don't think you can query a spreadsheet.

Comment: @AxGryndr Yes, you can.  I have nearly the exact code in one of my projects.  It's supported by the Excel OleDB driver.

Comment: Is the sheet in this experiment using the 12.0 or 4.0 driver (i.e. is it *.xls or *.xlsx)?  I'm really just curious as to whether you get the same error from both drivers.

Comment: Pick the correct name for the sheet.  Something like "[Sheet1$]", the default name.  Hard to believe that anybody would ever name their worksheet "Sheet Name".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment above have you tried this

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "$]";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

if (strFile.Trim().EndsWith(".xlsx"))
{
   strConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";", strFile);
}
else if (strFile.Trim().EndsWith(".xls"))
{
    strConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";", strFile);
}

OleDbConnection objXConn = new OleDbConnection(strConnectionString);
                objXConn.Open();
                OleDbCommand objCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + SheetName + "$]", objXConn);
                OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(objCommand);
                adp.Fill(ds);
                objXConn.Close();
```